# How to handle "--" in the shell script arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, sh

This question has 3 parts, and each alone is easy, but combined together is not trivial (at least for me) :)

Need write a script what should take as its arguments:

1. one name of another command
2. several arguments for the command
3. list of files

Examples:

```
./my_script head -100 a.txt b.txt ./xxx/*.txt
./my_script sed -n 's/xxx/aaa/' *.txt
```

and so on.

Inside my script for some reason I need distinguish

- what is the command
- what are the arguments for the command
- what are the files

so probably the most standard way write the above examples is:

```
./my_script head -100 -- a.txt b.txt ./xxx/*.txt
./my_script sed -n 's/xxx/aaa/' -- *.txt
```

**Question1:** Is here any better solution?

Processing in ./my_script (first attempt):

```
command="$1";shift
args=`echo $* | sed 's/--.*//'`
filenames=`echo $* | sed 's/.*--//'`

#... some additional processing ...

"$command" "$args" $filenames #execute the command with args and files
```

This solution will fail when the `filenames` will contain `spaces` and/or '--', e.g.
/some--path/to/more/idiotic file name.txt

**Question2:** How properly get `$command` its `$args` and `$filenames` for the later execution?

**Question3:** - how to achieve the following style of execution?

```
echo $filenames | $command $args #but want one filename = one line (like ls -1)
```

Is here nice shell solution, or need to use for example perl?

Comment: This would take a while to answer properly. 1. why use back-tics? They are way deprecated and unless you expect to be doing a lot of work on Solaris or AIX as root, not necessary. Use $(cmd)! 2. (more to your question), read up on getopt and getopts (for shell). I have seen numerous examples here, at least one that is quite detailed. Coupled with something like `while (( $# > 0 )) do processArgs ; shift ; done` will help. 3. consider using case statements. For `--` you might have to escape them or quote them or convert it to a charclass like `[-][-].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it sounds like you're trying to write a script that takes a command and a list of filenames and runs the command on each filename in turn. This can be done in one line in bash:

```
$ for file in a.txt b.txt ./xxx/*.txt;do head -100 "$file";done
$ for file in *.txt; do sed -n 's/xxx/aaa/' "$file";done
```

However, maybe I've misinterpreted your intent so let me answer your questions individually.

Instead of using "--" (which already has a different meaning), the following syntax feels more natural to me:

```
./my_script -c "head -100" a.txt b.txt ./xxx/*.txt
./my_script -c "sed -n 's/xxx/aaa/'" *.txt
```

To extract the arguments in bash, use `getopts`:

```
SCRIPT=$0

while getopts "c:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)
            command=$OPTARG
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "$command" ] || [ -z "$*" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT -c <command> file [file..]"
    exit
fi
```

If you want to run a command for each of the remaining arguments, it would look like this:

```
for target in "$@";do
     eval $command \"$target\"
done
```

If you want to read the filenames from STDIN, it would look more like this:

```
while read target; do
     eval $command \"$target\"
done
```

Comment: @TomShaw : Nice first post.  For the last block of code, maybe you want to prefix the interior of the loop with `eval`.  Thanks for doing the heavy listing. ;-)

Comment: The line `filenames=$*` is devastatingly awful in what is otherwise good code.  In general, don't use `$*`.  In this case in particular, do not use `$*`.  If you used a Bash array, then `"$@"` would be fine.  As it is, the loop is best written as `for target in "$@"; do ...; done`.  If the file names actually contain no spaces, then the `$*` is sort-of OK.  As soon as there are spaces in the names, `$*` mishandles everything.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, I've incorporated your fix

Answer (score 3):

The `$@` variable, when quoted will be able to group parameters as they should be:

```
for parameter in "$@"
do
    echo "The parameter is '$parameter'"
done
```

If given:

```
head -100 test this "File name" out
```

Will print

```
the parameter is 'head'
the parameter is '-100'
the parameter is 'test'
the parameter is 'this'
the parameter is 'File name'
the parameter is 'out'
```

Now, all you have to do is parse the loop out. You can use some very simple rules:

1. The first parameter is always the file name
2. The parameters that follow that start with a dash are parameters
3. After the "--" or once one doesn't start with a "-", the rest are all file names.

You can check to see if the first character in the parameter is a dash by using this:

```
if [[ "x${parameter}" == "x${parameter#-}" ]]
```

If you haven't seen this syntax before, it's a *left filter*. The `#` divides the two parts of the variable name. The first part is the name of the variable, and the second is the **glob** filter (not regular expression) to cut off. In this case, it's a single dash. As long as this statement isn't true, you know you have a parameter. BTW, the `x` may or may not be needed in this case. When you run a test, and you have a string with a dash in it, the test might mistake it for a parameter of the test and not the value.

Put it together would be something like this:

```
parameterFlag=""
for parameter in "$@"     #Quotes are important!
do
    if [[ "x${parameter}" == "x${parameter#-}" ]]
    then
         parameterFlag="Tripped!"
    fi
    if [[ "x${parameter}" == "x--" ]]
    then
         print "Parameter \"$parameter\" ends the parameter list"
         parameterFlag="TRIPPED!"
    fi
    if [ -n $parameterFlag ]
    then
        print "\"$parameter\" is a file"
    else
        echo "The parameter \"$parameter\" is a parameter"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `x` hack is only needed for ancient shells. Please don't use it, it makes code ugly.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, ...well -- there _are_ some corner cases where it can be needed in modern shells as well, but those cases only exist in `[ ]` (not `[[ ]]`) and when `test` is passed more than three arguments (thus, when `-a` or `-o` is used)... that being part of why the latest version of POSIX describes them as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

I don't think so, at least not if you need to do this for arbitrary commands.

**Question 3**

```
command=$1
shift
while [ $1 != '--' ]; do
    args="$args $1"
    shift
done
shift
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done | $command $args
```

**Question 2**

How does that differ from question 3?

Comment: echo $filenames | sed - will break, if the filename contain spaces. e.g. echo "file1.txt" "file2 with spaces.txt" - therefore asking - my 1st attempt is wrong.